# Can I run MSBuild scripts from the Visual Studio Code command palette?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-code

Can I run MSBuild scripts directly within Visual Studio Code Command Palette or do I need to open an external command prompt?

I have not yet seen any documentation regarding Visual Studio Code and MSBuild directly. What I have seen so far, demonstrates Grunt tasks.

Comment: Same as grunt works for msbuild. There should be an example in the tasks.json file regarding MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

In tasks.json, you can find:

```js
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "msbuild",
    "args": [
        // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
    ],
    "taskSelector": "/t:",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "tasks": [
        {  
            "taskName": "build",
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "silent",
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings
            // and infos in the output.
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

which works great for building C# projects. I still haven't found a way to run the `exe` file. I guess it has something to do with "Test" command...